# Customizr WP Theme remove links from post meta tags

Tags: php, wordpress, url, meta-tags

I searched and did not find this question has been posted before.

At the top of each post the meta data is displayed including author, entry date, updated date, and taxonomy. Each of these also include a url. I want to display the metas but remove the links. I have found the php file and succesfully modified it to achieve desired result. What I need help with is how to make these modifications within my child theme so the changes are not overridden after a theme update.

I have been trying to get some guidance from the theme publisher on their github account but so far no response.

Customizr Free version 4.0.11

Here are the details:

I was able to locate the php file: core/front/models/content/post-metas/class-model-post_metas.php

And I was able to locate and modify the portion of the function that inserts the url link into the author-meta element. NOTE, the example below only removes links from the author meta tag. Similar modifications are done for the other metas. This is a private function so I don't think I can call this from functions.php.

I made changes to the function named: czr_fn_get_meta_author()

```
private function czr_fn_get_meta_author() {
    $author_id = null;

    if ( is_single() )
      if ( ! in_the_loop() ) {
        global $post;
        $author_id = $post->post_author;
      }
    return apply_filters(
    'tc_author_meta',
    sprintf( '<span class="author vcard author_name"><a class="url fn n" href="%1$s" title="%2$s" rel="author">%3$s</a></span>' ,
        esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID', $author_id ) ) ),
        esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'View all posts by %s' , 'customizr' ), get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $author_id ) ) ),
        get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $author_id )
    )
);//end filter
  }
```

And here is the modified version:

```
  private function czr_fn_get_meta_author() {
    $author_id = null;

    if ( is_single() )
      if ( ! in_the_loop() ) {
        global $post;
        $author_id = $post->post_author;
      }
    return apply_filters(
        'tc_author_meta',
        sprintf( '<span class="author vcard author_name">%3$s</span>' ,
            esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID', $author_id ) ) ),
            esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'View all posts by %s' , 'customizr' ), get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $author_id ) ) ),
            get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $author_id )
        )
    );//end filter
  }
```

So I can figure out how to do the same for entry-meta and others. Now I just need to know how to make this work in my child theme so that it will not be erased by updates.

Please and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have a potential solution to this issue. I was able to take a copy of the file I listed above 'class-model-post-metas.php' and place that in my child theme using the same directory structure. I then modified the file to check if the user level of the post 'author' is set to subscriber. If so, I strip out the href. Otherwise, normal behavior is performed.

The reason for this is that when adding a user forum plugin called CM Answers Pro, the users are able to login and register using social login (oAuth). I default all new registrations at subscriber level. So all my forum participants are held at subscriber level. Which is what created this issue in the first place. Every time a new post is added to the forum, the user gets tagged as the 'author' of the post. Even though they do not have Author level privileges.

When a single post from the Q&A forum is displayed, Customizr sets the post metas, including links, for the 'author' name and the entry date. These links create 404's because they are constructed making the assumption each post in the Q&A forum is a blog post.

The code below the modifications that correctly remove the links from the post metas when the user is set to subscriber level. The modifications were made to the following two functions: czr_fn_get_meta_date() and czr_fn_get_meta_author(). You can compare this to the original source code available on the Customizr GitHub repo. https://github.com/presscustomizr/customizr

```
<?php
class CZR_post_metas_model_class extends CZR_Model {


  /* PUBLIC GETTERS */
  public function czr_fn_get_cat_list( $limit = false, $sep = '' ) {
    return 0 != esc_attr( czr_fn_opt( 'tc_show_post_metas_categories' ) ) ? $this -> czr_fn_get_meta( 'categories', $limit, $sep ) : '';
  }

  public function czr_fn_get_tag_list( $limit = false, $sep = '' ) {
    return 0 != esc_attr( czr_fn_opt( 'tc_show_post_metas_tags' ) ) ? $this -> czr_fn_get_meta( 'tags', $limit, $sep ) : '';
  }

  public function czr_fn_get_author( $before = null ) {
    return 0 != esc_attr( czr_fn_opt( 'tc_show_post_metas_author' ) ) ? $this -> czr_fn_get_meta( 'author', array( $before ) ) : '';
  }

  public function czr_fn_get_publication_date( $permalink = false, $before = null ) {
    return 0 != esc_attr( czr_fn_opt( 'tc_show_post_metas_publication_date' ) ) ? $this -> czr_fn_get_meta( 'pub_date', array(
        '',
        $permalink,
        $before = null ) ) : '';
  }

  public function czr_fn_get_update_date( $permalink = false, $before = null ) {
    return 0 != esc_attr( czr_fn_opt( 'tc_show_post_metas_update_date' ) ) &&
           false !== czr_fn_post_has_update() ?
                $this -> czr_fn_get_meta( 'up_date', array( '', $permalink ) ) : '';
  }
  /* END PUBLIC GETTERS */


  /* HELPERS */
  protected function czr_fn_get_meta( $meta, $params = array(), $separator = '' ) {

    $params = is_array( $params ) ? $params : array( $params );
    return czr_fn_stringify_array( call_user_func_array( array( $this, "czr_fn_meta_generate_{$meta}" ), $params ), $separator );

  }


  private function czr_fn_meta_generate_categories( $limit = false ) {
    return $this -> czr_fn_meta_generate_tax_list( $hierarchical = true, $limit );
  }

  private function czr_fn_meta_generate_tags( $limit = false ) {
    return $this -> czr_fn_meta_generate_tax_list( $hierarchical = false, $limit );
  }

  private function czr_fn_meta_generate_author( $before ) {
    $author = $this -> czr_fn_get_meta_author();
    $before = is_null($before) ? __( 'by&nbsp;', 'customizr-child' ) :'';
    return '<span class="author-meta">' . $before . $author . '</span>';
  }

  private function czr_fn_meta_generate_pub_date( $format = '', $permalink = false, $before = null ) {
    $date   = $this -> czr_fn_get_meta_date( 'publication', $format, $permalink );
    $before = is_null($before) ? __( 'Published&nbsp;', 'customizr' ) :'';

    return $before . $date;
  }

  private function czr_fn_meta_generate_up_date( $format = '', $permalink = false, $before = null ) {
    $date   = $this -> czr_fn_get_meta_date( 'update', $format, $permalink );
    $before = is_null($before) ? __( 'Updated&nbsp;', 'customizr' ) :'';

    return $before . $date;
  }


  protected function czr_fn_get_term_css_class( $_is_hierarchical ) {
    $_classes = array();

    if ( $_is_hierarchical )
      array_push( $_classes , 'tax__link' );
    else
      array_push( $_classes , 'tag__link btn btn-skin-dark-oh inverted' );

    return $_classes;
  }

  /**
  * Helper
  * Return the date post metas
  *
  * @package Customizr
  * @since Customizr 3.2.6
  */
  protected function czr_fn_get_meta_date( $pub_or_update = 'publication', $_format = '', $permalink = false ) {
    if ( 'short' == $_format )
      $_format = 'j M, Y';
    $_format = apply_filters( 'czr_meta_date_format' , $_format );
    $_use_post_mod_date = apply_filters( 'czr_use_the_post_modified_date' , 'publication' != $pub_or_update );
    // get user level to be used to turn meta links on or off
    $subscriber_level = get_the_author_meta('user_level');
    if ($subscriber_level == 0) {
        // user is a subscriber
        return apply_filters(
            'tc_date_meta',
             sprintf( '<span><time class="entry-date %3$s" datetime="%4$s">%5$s</time></span>' ,
               $permalink ? esc_url( get_the_permalink() ) : esc_url( get_day_link( get_the_time( 'Y' ), get_the_time( 'm' ), get_the_time( 'd' ) ) ),
               $permalink ? esc_attr( the_title_attribute( array( 'before' => __('Permalink to:&nbsp;', 'customizr'), 'echo' => false ) ) ) : esc_attr( get_the_time() ),
               'publication' == $pub_or_update ? 'published updated' : 'updated',
               $_use_post_mod_date ? esc_attr( get_the_modified_date('c') ) : esc_attr( get_the_date( 'c' ) ),
               $_use_post_mod_date ? esc_html( get_the_modified_date( $_format ) ) : esc_html( get_the_date( $_format ) )
             ),
             $_use_post_mod_date,
             $_format
        );//end filter
    } else {
        // user is not a subscriber
        return apply_filters(
          'tc_date_meta',
            sprintf( '<a href="%1$s" title="%2$s" rel="bookmark"><time class="entry-date %3$s" datetime="%4$s">%5$s</time></a>' ,
              $permalink ? esc_url( get_the_permalink() ) : esc_url( get_day_link( get_the_time( 'Y' ), get_the_time( 'm' ), get_the_time( 'd' ) ) ),
              $permalink ? esc_attr( the_title_attribute( array( 'before' => __('Permalink to:&nbsp;', 'customizr'), 'echo' => false ) ) ) : esc_attr( get_the_time() ),
              'publication' == $pub_or_update ? 'published updated' : 'updated',
              $_use_post_mod_date ? esc_attr( get_the_modified_date('c') ) : esc_attr( get_the_date( 'c' ) ),
              $_use_post_mod_date ? esc_html( get_the_modified_date( $_format ) ) : esc_html( get_the_date( $_format ) )
            ),
            $_use_post_mod_date,
            $_format
        );//end filter
    }
  }

  /**
  * Helper
  * Return the post author metas
  *
  * @package Customizr
  * @since Customizr 3.2.6
  */

  // LET'S SEE IF WE CAN UPDATE THIS FUNCTION TO CHECK IF 'AUTHOR' IS ACTUALLY AN AUTHOR
  // BECUASE POSTS FROM THE CM ANSWERS PLUGIN ARE SUBSCRIBERS

  private function czr_fn_get_meta_author() {
    $author_id = null;
    if ( is_single() )
        $subscriber_level = 0;
        if ( ! in_the_loop() ) {
            global $post;
            $author_id = $post->post_author;
        }
        $subscriber_level = get_the_author_meta('user_level');
        // if ($subscriber_level == 0) {
        //     print_r("Subscriber ");
        // } else {
        //     print_r("Not Subscriber ");
        // }
        if($subscriber_level == 0) {
            // user role is subscriber
            return apply_filters(
                'tc_author_meta',
                sprintf( '<span class="author vcard author_name">%3$s</span>' ,
                    esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID', $author_id ) ) ),
                    esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'View all posts by %s' , 'customizr' ), get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $author_id ) ) ),
                    get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $author_id )
                )
            );//end filter
        } else {
            // user role is higher than subscriber level
            return apply_filters(
              'tc_author_meta',
              sprintf( '<span class="author vcard author_name"><a class="url fn n" href="%1$s" title="%2$s" rel="author">%3$s</a></span>' ,
                  esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID', $author_id ) ) ),
                  esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'View all posts by %s' , 'customizr' ), get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $author_id ) ) ),
                  get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $author_id )
              )
            );//end filter
        }

  }


  /**
  * Helper
  * @return string of all the taxonomy terms (including the category list for posts)
  * @param  hierarchical tax boolean => true = categories like, false = tags like
  *
  * @package Customizr
  * @since Customizr 3.0
  */
  private function czr_fn_meta_generate_tax_list( $hierarchical, $limit = false ) {
    $post_terms = $this -> czr_fn_get_term_of_tax_type( $hierarchical, $limit );
    if ( ! $post_terms )
      return;
    $_terms_html_array  = array_map( array( $this , 'czr_fn_meta_term_view' ), $post_terms );
    return $_terms_html_array;
  }


  /**
  * Helper
  * @return string of the single term view
  * @param  $term object
  *
  * @package Customizr
  * @since Customizr 3.3.2
  */
  private function czr_fn_meta_term_view( $term ) {
    $_is_hierarchical  =  is_taxonomy_hierarchical( $term -> taxonomy );

    $_classes      = czr_fn_stringify_array( apply_filters( 'czr_meta_tax_class', $this -> czr_fn_get_term_css_class( $_is_hierarchical ), $_is_hierarchical, $term ) );


    // (Rocco's PR Comment) : following to this https://wordpress.org/support/topic/empty-articles-when-upgrading-to-customizr-version-332
    // I found that at least wp 3.6.1  get_term_link($term->term_id, $term->taxonomy) returns a WP_Error
    // Looking at the codex, looks like we can just use get_term_link($term), when $term is a term object.
    // Just this change avoids the issue with 3.6.1, but I thought should be better make a check anyway on the return type of that function.
    $_term_link    = is_wp_error( get_term_link( $term ) ) ? '' : get_term_link( $term );
    $_to_return    = $_term_link ? '<a %1$s href="%2$s" title="%3$s"> <span>%4$s</span> </a>' :  '<span %1$s> %4$s </span>';
    $_to_return    = $_is_hierarchical ? $_to_return : '<li>' . $_to_return . '</li>';
    return apply_filters( 'czr_meta_term_view' , sprintf($_to_return,
        $_classes ? 'class="'. $_classes .'"' : '',
        $_term_link,
        esc_attr( sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s", 'customizr' ), $term -> name ) ),
        $term -> name
      )
    );
  }


  /**
  * Helper to return the current post terms of specified taxonomy type : hierarchical or not
  *
  * @return boolean (false) or array
  * @param  boolean : hierarchical or not
  * @package Customizr
  * @since Customizr 3.1.20
  *
  */
  private function czr_fn_get_term_of_tax_type( $hierarchical = true, $limit = false ) {
    //var declaration
    $post_type              = get_post_type( czr_fn_get_id() );
    $tax_list               = get_object_taxonomies( $post_type, 'object' );
    $_tax_type_list         = array();
    $_tax_type_terms_list   = array();

    if ( empty($tax_list) )
      return false;

    //filter the post taxonomies
    while ( $_tax_object = current($tax_list) ) {
      // cast $_tax_object stdClass object in an array to access its property 'public'
      // fix for PHP version < 5.3 (?)
      $_tax_object = (array) $_tax_object;
      //Is the object well defined ?
      if ( ! isset($_tax_object['name']) ) {
        next($tax_list);
        continue;
      }
      $_tax_name = $_tax_object['name'];
      //skip the post format taxinomy
      if ( ! $this -> czr_fn_is_tax_authorized( $_tax_object, $post_type ) ) {
        next($tax_list);
        continue;
      }
      if ( (bool) $hierarchical === (bool) $_tax_object['hierarchical'] )
        $_tax_type_list[$_tax_name] = $_tax_object;

      next($tax_list);
    }
    if ( empty($_tax_type_list) )
      return false;

    $found = 0;

    //fill the post terms array
    foreach ($_tax_type_list as $tax_name => $data ) {
      $_current_tax_terms = get_the_terms( czr_fn_get_id() , $tax_name );
      //If current post support this tax but no terms has been assigned yet = continue
      if ( ! $_current_tax_terms )
        continue;
      while( $term = current($_current_tax_terms) ) {
        $_tax_type_terms_list[$term -> term_id] = $term;
        if ( $limit > 0 && ++$found == $limit )
          break 2;
        next($_current_tax_terms);
      }
    }

    /*if ( ! empty($_tax_type_terms_list) && $limit > 0 )
      $_tax_type_terms_list = array_slice( $_tax_type_terms_list, 0, $limit );
*/
    return empty($_tax_type_terms_list) ? false : apply_filters( "czr_tax_meta_list" , $_tax_type_terms_list , $hierarchical );
  }

  /**
  * Helper : check if a given tax is allowed in the post metas or not
  * A tax is authorized if :
  * 1) not in the exclude list
  * 2) AND not private
  *
  * @return boolean (false)
  * @param  $post_type, $_tax_object
  * @package Customizr
  * @since Customizr 3.3+
  *
  */
  private function czr_fn_is_tax_authorized( $_tax_object , $post_type ) {
    $_in_exclude_list = in_array(
      $_tax_object['name'],
      apply_filters_ref_array ( 'czr_exclude_taxonomies_from_metas' , array( array('post_format') , $post_type , czr_fn_get_id() ) )
    );
    $_is_private = false === (bool) $_tax_object['public'] && apply_filters_ref_array( 'czr_exclude_private_taxonomies', array( true, $_tax_object['public'], czr_fn_get_id() ) );
    return ! $_in_exclude_list && ! $_is_private;
  }


  /* Customizer: allow dynamic visibility in the preview */
  function czr_fn_body_class( $_classes/*array*/ ) {
    if ( ! czr_fn_is_customizing() )
      return $_classes;

    if ( 0 == esc_attr( czr_fn_opt( 'tc_show_post_metas' ) ) )
       $_classes[] = 'hide-all-post-metas';

    if (
        ( is_singular() && ! is_page() && ! czr_fn_is_real_home() && 0 == esc_attr( czr_fn_opt( 'tc_show_post_metas_single_post' ) ) ) ||
        ( ! is_singular() && ! czr_fn_is_real_home() && ! is_page() && 0 == esc_attr( czr_fn_opt( 'tc_show_post_metas_post_lists' ) ) ) ||
        ( czr_fn_is_real_home() ) && 0 == esc_attr( czr_fn_opt( 'tc_show_post_metas_home' ) )
    )
      $_classes[] = 'hide-post-metas';

    return $_classes;
  }
}//end of class
```